# Deploying Laravel on Ubuntu server

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5

So i have completed local dev on the app i am working on. I am just battling to make it work on our internal test server(Ubuntu 16.4).

What i have tried.

1. Transfered my project over to the server's **`/var/www/html/`**.
2. Installed Composer on the server.
3. **`cd`** into my app directory and ran **`composer install`** to install all app dependencies.
4. Changed permisions for **`/storage`** folder to '775'
5. When i browser my server ip **`http://192.168.X.XXX/myapp`**, I get the **403** error:

> You don't have permission to access **`/myapp/`** on this server.

To test if the issues is not Laravel, made another folder in var/ww/html/testblog and create a **`index.php`** with **`echo 'hello'`**. When i browse **`192.168.xx.xx`**, It works fine.

Is there a step by step guide on how to deploy the app on your SSH server, Not shared hosting

Comment: htpp://192.168.X.XXX/myapp/public access this url.or use php artisan serve commend to start the server

Comment: You can check this for steps: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-for-apache/

Comment: You might need to set apache or nginx document root to `/public` folder.

Comment: @TahaPaksu - Do you mean `/myapp/public` ?

Comment: nope, the public folder which is the **sibling** of the app folder.

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed this steps:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/html/myapp
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/myapp/storage
```

Reference: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-for-apache/

Comment: If you look at my question u will see that i changed `storage` to 775.

And i also did changed group to www-data.

Comment: You should also do `sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/html/myapp`, that would all permissions to web-service.